# How can React use .env in rails derectory?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails

I searched it but I couldn't find details..

From my search, create-react-app can't refer .env to another directory.

My constitution of directory is following the below.

- app
- bin
- config
- db
- frontend

   - public

   - src

   - static
- lib
- public
- vendor
- .env ← here!!

Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just needed the .env file and to add this code on this file - config/webpack/development.js

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')

dotenv.config()
```

I hope it's working

Comment: Thank you! you mean using dotenv to call .env on root directory? I can't figure out how it works. And how can react call dotenv? sorry..

Comment: Okay You need to understand how dotenv work this blog maybe help to learn dotenv

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dotenv